# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf': Singleton bean creation

Tags: java, maven, dependency-injection, cxf, spring-aop

I'm trying to create an aspect for logging for my helix service.
I'm stuck with this error since a while now. Would appreciate if you guys could help me out.
The following is my XML :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"

xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd

    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs
    http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.0.xsd">

<import resource="classpath:framework.xml" />
<import resource="classpath*:config/jackson.spring.xml" />



<bean id="wordEchoBean" class="com.example.mypackage.JavaFileforTestAspect"/>


<bean id="testAspect" class="com.example.mypackage.TestAspect" />

<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect id="aspects" ref="testAspect">
        <aop:pointcut id="pointCutBefore"
            expression="execution(* com.example.mypackage.*(..))" />
        <aop:before method="doBefore" pointcut-ref="pointCutBefore" />
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>

<jaxrs:server id="wordEchoService" depends-on="modulesInitialization">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="wordEchoBean" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
```

Let me know if you need any more details for the above.

The following is the entire Stack Trace.

```
 ERROR [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (MSC service thread 1-4) Destroy method on bean with name '(inner bean)' threw an exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf': Singleton bean creation not allowed while the singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:212)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1093)
at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.Jsr250BeanPostProcessor.getResourceManager(Jsr250BeanPostProcessor.java:91)
at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.Jsr250BeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeDestruction(Jsr250BeanPostProcessor.java:153)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:498)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:474)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:442)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1066)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:472)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850)
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:89)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
```

Answer (score -1):

this mostly happen because on some what you run the application on the server before. due to this it is unable to create the bean. so, as far as my understanding, in my case when i face this problem i go to the tomcat option or any server option and reset the deployment time to a longer one. for instance tomcat will undeploy any instance of the application and restart again if you provide the time need to do this job.

my advice is when ever you run the application you need to make sure that you undeploy the earlier run and also stop the server so that it automatically start by itself.

i hope this will help

keya